# C# threading with max thread count then wait

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a for loop that spawns threads... I want it to spawn 5 threads then wait until it drops down to 4 then spawn another one.

Basically, if I have 100 records, I want to to process 5 at a time.  Which is the preferred approach?

Comment: Have you considered PLINQ .AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)?

Comment: You count with the Semaphore class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *preferred* approach would probably be to just use one of the built-in mechanisms for this.

For example, [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) has the option of specifying the [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) to use, which corresponds to the maximum number of threads used.

This would let you just write something like:

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 };
Parallel.ForEach(records, options, rec =>
{
    ProcessRecord(rec);
});
```

If you're "record processing" is a mapping or query operation, another good option is to use PLINQ's [WithDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx) to limit the parallelism:

```
var results = records.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(5).Select(r => ProcessRecord(rec)).Where(result => result.Foo); // Some query...
```

I would choose the first option if you're just "processing" each record (ie: ProcessRecord is a void method), and the second if you're doing some type of mapping operation or query over the records, and returning results from the record processing.

Comment: This seems very simple. So I dont need to do any special threading at all? It will take care of this all for me?  Thanks:0 )  and all my variables in "ProcessRecord" will be in its own thread I assume.

Comment: @magic-c0d3r Yes - this handles all of the "threading" for you, which is why it's typically better.  Assume that each call to ProcessRecord happens on its own thread (they get reused, but that's a safe assumption).  You still are responsible for all synchronization of data, so you need to make sure that `ProcessRecord` is thread safe and not using shared data inappropriately.

Answer (score 2):

I would stronly suggest using the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or better yet the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).